# If not statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statement which doesn't append the 'id' '1062066', but it is not working

My code:

```
if not event['id'] in ['1062066']
```

JSON:

```
"id":1062066,
"number":9,
"name":"COASTAL MIDWEST TRANSPORT HANDICAP",
"startsAt":"2020-10-03T09:25:00+00:00",
"url":"https:\/\/www.odds.com.au\/horse-racing\/kalgoorlie\/race-9\/?date=2020-10-03",
"isAbandoned":false,
"resulted":false,
"results":null,
"meetingId":184543,
"regionIconUrl":"https:\/\/puntcdn.com\/flags\/@2x\/AU@2x.png",
"regionName":"Australia"
```

Comment: Later container of your `if`-`else` contains _str_, whereas `event["id"]` is _int_.  Try convert LHS as `str` (`str(event["id"])`)

Answer (score 1):

The `id` in JSON response is of type `int`. You will need to convert the id to `str` in order to check.

```py
if not str(event['id']) in ['1062066']
```

Comment: Why use str instead of int? `if event['id'] not in [1062066]`

Comment: From you question, if statement is checking for an `id` type `int` against a list of `id's` type `str`. From the JSON response, it looks like `id` is of type `int`.  So either create a list of `id's` types `int` or change the type of `id` to `str`. Anyone will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`if not str(event['id']) == str(1062066):`